# ElasticSearch PORT 9300 connection refused

Tags: java, elasticsearch, docker, netty

I've deployed Elasticsearch 5.1.2 in docker version 1.12.6.
When i run telnet to 9200 and 9300 port of the server using localhost then it says the connection is successful.
But when i run telnet to 9300 port of the server using the server address it says connection refused.

I've also tried to execute some search request from my JAVA application to Elasticsearch using the server HOST name and the PORT 9300 then I get the following error:

```
loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin]

loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]

loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.MustachePlugin]

loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin]

loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]

failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{JElPum7oR5Szj0KG45ULww}{elasticsearch}{<**serverIP**>:9300}], removed from nodes list

org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][<**serverIP**>:9300] connect_timeout[30s]

at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannelsLight(Netty4Transport.java:340) ~[transport-netty4-client-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]

at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.connectToNode(TcpTransport.java:410) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]

at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.connectToNodeLight(TcpTransport.java:382) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]

at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLight(TransportService.java:303) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]

at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:392) [elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]

at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:338) [elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]

at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.addTransportAddresses(TransportClientNodesService.java:179) [elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]

at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.addTransportAddress(TransportClient.java:301) [elasticsearch-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]

at com.goglides.esservice.clientservice.ClientService.createClient(ClientService.java:36) [classes/:?]

at com.goglides.esservice.clientservice.ClientService.getClient(ClientService.java:23) [classes/:?]

at com.goglides.esservice.util.SearchQueryExecutor.getSearchRequestBuilder(SearchQueryExecutor.java:50) [classes/:?]

at com.goglides.esservice.util.SearchQueryExecutor.execute(SearchQueryExecutor.java:27) [classes/:?]

at com.goglides.esservice.ESService.searchGlides(ESService.java:37) [classes/:?]

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:301) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509) [catalina.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.39]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2445) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.39]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.39]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]

Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: elasticsearch/172.17.0.3:9300

at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]

at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]

at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:639) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]

at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:536) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]

at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:490) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]

at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]

at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873) ~[netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]

... 1 more
```

My configuration in elasticsearch.yml is:-

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0
cluster.name: goglides_cluster
node.name: dev-node
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

**Docker run Command Use:**

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 0.0.0.0:9300:9300 -v /data/config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config --name=elasticsearch elasticsearch:5.1.2
```

**And tried this command for JAVA application**

```
docker run -d --name=goglides-search -p 8060:8080 --link=elasticsearch <java-app-image>
```

**I can curl elasticsearch:9200 from goglides-search container**

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: You're using Docker? Did you link the containers? Expose the ports?

Comment: Yes, I have linked the containers and even the port 9200 is curl from inside the image

Comment: Your error is on port 9300, so why do you think curl-ing 9200 would prove you can connect?

Comment: Is your docker host a hosted service? did you open the firewall?

Comment: Because Elasticsearch runs on port 9200 and 9300 and since I've defined these port in the same way 
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 0.0.0.0:9300:9300 -v /data/config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config --name=elasticsearch elasticsearch:5.1.2

Comment: Dear @MohanG, have you found a solution for your case? I have same problem with elastic 5, but for same configuration elastic 2 working well. 127.0.0.1:9200->9200/tcp, 127.0.0.1:9300->9300/tcp . my settings

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 ....
```

IMO, you should try without `0.0.0.0`, only ports in command line.

Comment: maybe you're using a ufw firewall and your rules are not up to date?